# Pandas read_html misses table with several rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, html-table

I'm scraping a website and in order to get the table I'm using `pd.read_html`.

I get the node doing this:

```
table=WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
By.XPATH,'//tbody[ancestor::div[contains(@id,"cornerOddsDiv")]]')))

newt=pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

This returns:

> ValueError: No tables found

Giving the table node this output:

```
table.get_attribute('outerHTML')

>>'<tbody><tr><th colspan="10" align="center" class="bg1">365 Corner Odds</th></tr><tr bgcolor="#FCEAAB"><td colspan="10" align="center"><strong>Over/Under</strong></td></tr><tr onclick="goCorner(1510721)" style="cursor:pointer;" align="center" class="bg1" id="trCornerTotal" odds="1.19,0.25,0.72"><td width="14%" bgcolor="#EBF2F8">early</td><td width="10%" class="bg2">1 </td><td width="10%" class="bg2">10.5</td><td width="10%" class="bg2">0.8</td><td width="6%" class="bg2"><a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/history/corner.aspx?id=1510721&amp;companyid=8" target="_blank">detail</a></td><td width="14%" bgcolor="#EBF2F8">0.25</td><td width="10%" class="bg2">1</td><td width="10%" class="bg2">0.72</td><td width="10%" class="bg2">0.8</td><td width="6%" class="bg2"><a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/history/corner.aspx?id=1510721&amp;companyid=8" target="_blank">detail</a></td></tr></tbody>'
```

Why is it not working? I have followed the same procedure for other tables and they did work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. The node is of a structure like the following

```
<div>
   <div>
     <table>
        <tbody>
           <tr>..</tr>
           <tr>..</tr>
           ...
        </tbody>

Etc
```

The key is, instead of passing the node of tbody, for reasons unknown to me,I have to pass table node, and then it works just as fine as the others when using tbody.

So, it would be:

```
table=WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
By.XPATH,'//table[contains(@class,"bhTable") and 
ancestor::div[contains(@id,"cornerOddsDiv")]]')))
```

and that returns the desired output